# Remove the '\xa0' when output a dataframe to a csv

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries, I first convert the list to a dataframe, and plan to output the dataframe as a csv. I use the following codes:

```
import pandas as pd
detail_data = [
               {'applyId' : 'fca45afe3af',
                'usual' :'胜' ,
                'Type' : '车（M1类）' ,
                'publicTime' : '2021-1',
                'oversrasName' : '英',
                'vehicleNumber' : 'RANGE ROVER (AJ5JH)',
                'engineNumber' : 'PT306',
                'transmissionType' : 'AT',
                'fuelType' : '油',
                'Quality' : '111',
                'displacement' : '111',
                'maximumDesign' : '222',
                'maximum' : '333',
                'driveType' : '4×4',
                'suburbanConditions' : '11.1',
                'urbanConditions' : '12.2',
                'comprehensiveConditions' : '13.3',
                'uniqId' : 'NH202' }, 
               {'applyId' : 'fca45afe3af',
                'usual' :'NT' ,
                'Type' : '车（M1类）' ,
                'publicTime' : '2021-1',
                'oversrasName' : '英',
                'vehicleNumber' : 'RANGE ROVER (AJ5JH)',
                'engineNumber' : 'PT306',
                'transmissionType' : 'AT',
                'fuelType' : '油',
                'Quality' : '111',
                'displacement' : '111',
                'maximumDesign' : '222',
                'maximum' : '333',
                'driveType' : '三',
                'suburbanConditions' : '',
                'urbanConditions' : '',
                'comprehensiveConditions' : '',
                'uniqId' : 'NH202' }
]
path = './tests.csvvehicle_energy_consumption.csv'
data_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(detail_data)
data_df.to_csv(path_or_buf=path,sep = ',', header=True,index=False, encoding = "gbk")
```

but I get the following error:

```
'gbk' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position 77: illegal multibyte sequence
```

i tried the following code to remove the `'\xa0'`, but it didn't work.

```
data_df.replace(u'\xa0',u' ', inplace = True)
```

How do i remove `'\xa0'`

Many thanks.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for the use of the GBK encoding? Why not use Unicode? That said, yes, those xA0 bytes (nonbreaking space) could probably be removed or replaced with a regular space without too much loss of information.

Answer (score 1):

i needed to chanage some things but with this code it work for me

```
import pandas as pd
detail_data = [{"a":1,"b":1},{"a":2,"b":2},{"a":3,"b":3}]
data_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(detail_data)

data_df.to_csv(path_or_buf="./tests.csv",sep = ',', header=True,index=False, encoding = "gbk")
```

i put the keys in the dictonary as strings and hardcoded a path_or_buf.

if the problem isn't the keys of the strings, it's probably the filename.

Comment: The encoding is the secret.